# Changing CSS Styles with javascript for a phone app

Tags: javascript, css

I have a  page that will be displayed on a phone.  On the page I have a link
when clicked runs a javascript script.  In the script I want to hide a 
with the class name, content and display the  with the class name, sidebar1.  I put an alert in the script to show that the script runs when the
link is clicked. It will come out when I get the script running.  Right now the
commands after the alert do not work.  Can someone help?  Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displaymenu() {
    alert("I'm the menu");
    document.className.content.style.display = 'none';
    document.className.sidebar1.style.display = '!important';
};

</script>
```

Comment: Please can you post your html?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClassName").style.display = "none";
document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar1").style.cssText = 'display:inline !important';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a style on a particular element, you should use the element id:

```
   document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getElementsByClassName()

```
document.getElementsByClassName('content');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

or with jQuery

```
$('.className').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displaymenu() {
    alert("I'm the menu");
    var content = document.querySelector(".content"),
        sidebar1 = document.querySelector(".sidebar1")
    content.style.display = 'none';
    sidebar1.style.display = 'block';
};

</script>
```